# Zend Navigation - All XML possible options

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-config-xml

I've searching for a while now but I didn't anything concluent. I'm searching for a blog or anything that explain and shows all possible options of a Zend_Navigation XML config file.

I know those for now:

```
<module>
<controller>
<action>
<route>
<params> (array)
<pages> (array)
<visible>
<label>
```

Those are all I know. If someone has a complete list, I would be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the options are the same as the constructor options for the `Zend_Navigation_Page` objects, and these are all listed in the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.navigation.pages.html.